# Can a script tag be blocking if the HTTP response is 404?

Tags: javascript

If I add a script to the DOM in the beginning of `<head>` using document.createElement etc, and the script resource is not found (error 404) does this or could this block other scripts?

Comment: What does "...in the beginning..." mean? What do you mean by "using document.createElement **etc**"? (My emphasis.) Code is worth 1024 words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is if you add it with `document.write` it will delay rendering of any further content until the `script` tag has resolved (in your case to a 404) and has been fully evaluated. This is part of the rendering process, and is mostly so your browser can cope with other `document.write` calls in the script being added.

If a script is inserting another script using `document.write`, the issue remains the same.

On the other hand, if you are using `document.createElement` followed by an append/prepend, and you've waited for the DOM to be ready, you will not have this issue.

As such, if your script takes a long while to get to a 404 state, it'll take a while for the page to render. Logically enough, reducing this lag time (through better content providers, less latency...) or offloading the insertion and execution of scripts after the DOM has loaded, can remedy that.

This happens to be explained in the optimization tips from Google: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS